# UTF-8 Server.UrlEncode problem in ASP Classic

Tags: php, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm having a bit of bother URL encoding a string of UTF-8 encoded text to pass over HTTP. I am using Server.URlEncode in classic ASP (vbscript) to do the encoding on the "é" character.

It produces the following string,

%C3%83%C2%A9

The system I am talking to over HTTP is PHP however and it cannot decode this string. Using a PHP encoder at http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php the same character encoded using the PHP URL encoding method comes out as,

%E9

Does anyone know how I can successfully encode my UTF-8 encoded strings in my ASP so that the PHP system can successfully decode them?

Answer (score 6):

> %C3%83%C2%A9

That's encoded too much: the string is written as UTF-8, read back in as ISO-8859-1, then written as UTF-8 again before being hex-encoded!

> %E9

That's encoded too little: the string is written out as plain ISO-8859-1 and hex-encoded. This is fine if the PHP script you are talking to is expecting ISO-8859-1, but modern web systems should be talking UTF-8, in which case the sequence you want it to look like:

> %C3%A9

(That's encoded just right!)

> I am using Server.URLEncode in classic ASP

Classic ASP has, unfortunately, some serious deficiencies in processing Unicode. You can set @ CODEPAGE=65001 (and Response.Charset="UTF-8") to produce UTF-8 pages, but your internal string type is still encoded in the system codepage, and any data grabbed from form submissions or the database will be read into that encoding.

So you can URLEncode() a literal chr 233 to get the correct output OK, but if you're getting the data from a UTF-8-encoded ‘é’ in a form submission, you'll end up with ‘Ã©’ — the UTF-8 sequence misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 (actually cp1252, the Windows equivalent).

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
Function URLEncodeWithCodepage(value, myCodepage)
    Dim cpOriginal
    cpOriginal = Response.Codepage
    Response.Codepage = myCodepage
    URLEncodeWithCodepage = Server.URLEncode(value)
    Response.Codepage = cpOriginal
End Function
```

You may use it with

```
encodedValue = URLEncodeWithCodepage(value, 65001)
```

to get it UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Is there difference between **Session.CodePage** and **Response.CodePage** ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the head of the ASP-page that returns the data

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my work around.

Create a new ASP file coded in JScript (not in VBScript) an call it urlEncodeUTF8.asp:

```
<%@ Language="JScript" %>
<%
    Response.CharSet="UTF-8"
    Response.Write(encodeURIComponent(Request("s")))
%>
```

In your main ASP file write this code:

```
FUNCTION URLEncodeUTF8(ByVal str)
    URLEncodeUTF8 = ""
    On Error Resume NEXT
    Err.Clear
    postStr = "s=" & Server.URLEncode(str)
    sURL = "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & "/urlEncodeUTF8.asp"
    SET xmlHTTPObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    WITH xmlHTTPObj
        .SetTimeouts 2000, 2000, 2000, 5000
        .Open "POST", sURL, false
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(postStr)
        .Send postStr
        xmlHttpResponse = .responseText
        IF Err.number=0 AND .Status=200 THEN
            URLEncodeUTF8 = xmlHttpResponse
        END IF
    END WITH    
    SET xmlHTTPObj = NOTHING
    On Error Goto 0
END FUNCTION
```

Now you can URLEncode your string using the above function:

```
Response.Write(URLEncodeUTF8("é"))
```

In this case the result will be:

```
%C3%A9
```

Answer (score 0):

[bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616029/3626160) above explains well why the built in function doesn't work, and why changing the `CodePage` of either the `Response` or the `Session` isn't enough to change that.

But you don't have to use an extra JavaScript page to have a working custom function. The below VBScript function will escape UTF8 characters including those that use more than one byte such as `%C3%A9` in the case of `é`.

```vb
Function UrlEncode(url)
    For i = 1 To Len(url)
        n = Asc(Mid(url,i,1))
        If (n >= 48 And n <= 57) Or (n >= 65 And n <= 90) Or (n >= 97 And n <= 122) Then
            UrlEncode = UrlEncode & Mid(url,i,1)
        Else
            ChrHex = Hex(Asc(Mid(url,i,1)))
            For j = 0 to (Len(ChrHex) / 2) - 1
                UrlEncode = UrlEncode & "%" & Mid(ChrHex,(2*j)+1,2)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

URLEncodeWithCodepage(value, 65001)  by David Cain and Santiago is the same as Server.URLEncode(value).

The best way I found is JavaScript runat server !

```
<script language="javascript1.2" runat="server">
function twEntitesHTMLEncode(sChaineTemp) {
    var buffer = "";
    for (var i=0;i<=sChaineTemp.length-1;i++) {
        buffer = buffer + "&#" + sChaineTemp.charCodeAt(i);
    }
   return buffer;
}
</script> 

<%=twEntitesHTMLEncode("école")%>
```